# Using multiple delimiters in while loop for fstream c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in a `.dat` file with `ifstream.` When I read the problem my issue is I need to set 2 delimiters. 
first one being a `','` second one being a `'\n'`

my file format is like this, 
item1,item2,item3
item4,item5,item6

My issue is adding the '\n' with the way I have it now. 
I am currently add the ',' in as the delimiter in my while loop like this

```
 while (std::getline(infile, line, ','))
```

But then getting the '\n' is kiling me. So in the while loop I tried stuff like this,

```
    std::getline(infile, inp.item.group, ',' );
    std::getline(infile, inp.item.total_pay, ',' );
    std::getline(infile, inp.item.quantity, '\n' );
```

But obviously I am not understanding how to access each one of my items and give them each their own delimiter.

Should I not be able to read in the whole line like I am using the new line as the delimiter then just split everything up like i'm trying in the while loop?

My relevant code is as follows,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct Input
{
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item);

    std::string group;
    std::string total_pay;
    float quantity;

    // default constructor. sets up zero-elements
    Input() : group(), total_pay(), quantity()
    {
    }

    Input(std::string groupIn, std::string total_payIn, float quantityIn) :
    group(std::move(groupIn)),
    total_pay(total_payIn),
    quantity(quantityIn)
    {
    }

    // Accessors
    std::string const& getGroup() const { return group; }
    std::string getTotalPay() const { return total_pay; }
    float getQuantity() const { return quantity; }
};

// global free function for extracting an Input item from an input stream
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item)
{
    return (inp >> item.group >> item.total_pay >> item.quantity);
}

// global operator for inserting to a stream
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item)
{
    outp
    << item.getGroup() << ", "
    << item.getTotalPay() << ", "
    << item.getQuantity();
    return outp;
}

struct ctype : std::ctype<char>
{
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> table(classic_table(),
                                       classic_table() + table_size);
        table[','] |= space;
        return &table[0];
    }

    ctype() : std::ctype<char>(make_table()) { }
};

int main() {

    std::ifstream infile("employee.dat");

    // one line per item enforced.
    std::vector<Input> data;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Input inp;
        infile.imbue(std::locale(iss.getloc(), new ctype));
        std::vector<Input> data((std::istream_iterator<Input>(std::cin)), {});

        if (iss >> inp) // calls our extraction operator >>
            data.push_back(inp);
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid input line: " << line << '\n';
    }

    // dump all of them to stdout. calls our insertion operator <<
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Input>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick fix. Use a getline with first delimiter. Then getline again on the resulting string (using stringstream) for second delimiter.

Comment: I appreciate the quick fix. But I really want to understand where i'm messing up so I understand for the future. Is my thought process not logical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the delimiter using a custom `std::ctype` facet. Then your formatted extractor will take care of the rest:

```c++
struct ctype : std::ctype<char>
{
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> table(classic_table(),
                                       classic_table() + table_size);
        table[','] |= space;
        return &table[0];
    }

    ctype() : std::ctype<char>(make_table()) { }
};

// ...
int main()
{
    // ...
    infile.imbue(std::locale(iss.getloc(), new ctype));
    std::vector<Input> data((std::istream_iterator<Input>(std::cin)), {});
}
```

Comment: So your saying by using the custom std::ctype facet as you have shown, it will take the , as a space then revert to the default delimiter of '\n' and work fine just by adding the new struct you have provided?

Comment: @NDiaz Formatted extractors use whitespace as delimiters. By default, the newline character (`'\n'`) and space is classified as whitespace by the stream's default `std::ctype` facet. This code modify's the facet so that, in addition to the newline character, it classifies the comma `,` as whitespace as well. So anywhere the stream finds `,` it will treat it as a whitespace character. The `imbue()` call is what installs the facet into the stream's locale so anywhere from that point on the stream classifies the comma as additional whitespace.

Comment: You might remove the flag `space` from all space classified characters and set it for ',' and for '\n', only. An issue will persist: Does each data set in each line hold the expected number of elements?

Comment: @DieterLücking What does the expected number of elements have to do with the original question? Also, this example was meant to *add* an additional whitespace character. I didn't intend to take away the classification of other characters.

Comment: Yes they have all the expected values. I cannot for the life of me to get this to work. grr. When I implement your example it throws an invalid line error by each entry. I updated my question with all my code and the way I added your example.

Comment: @NDiaz My code was a bit wrong. You weren't supposed to create `data` inside the loop as it hides the one created outside the `while()` loop. Also, the `if (iss >> inp)` part wasn't needed as the `istream_iterator` part was just my way of making that code shorter. And lastly, I used `std::cin` inside `istream_iterator` instead of `iss`. Check the working code here -- http://rextester.com/OYEFE37143

Comment: When I compile on osx with gnu compiler I get this 
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
wuno:vect ndiaz$ g++ -o vect main.cpp
main.cpp:86:59: error: expected expression
            data.assign(std::istream_iterator<Input>(iss),{});                             
1 error generated.
wuno:vect ndiaz$ ./vect
Invalid input line: Horowitz,Jake,1200.24
Invalid input line: Flabitz,Bubba,1712.38

Comment: @NDiaz Replace `{}` with `std::istream_iterator<Input>()` and try this code -- http://rextester.com/USNKGU88421

Comment: The first two lines prepennd the Invalid input line: but then all the rest of the lines are fine...

Comment: Ok i got it working... damn file had two errors in it. thanks a ton for all of your help!